# How to align edittext and button next to each other inside relativelayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

There is a very similar question here:

[How to put an EditText and Button next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273452/how-to-put-an-edittext-and-button-next-to-each-other)

However, that question has a LinearLayout as a root element, and my layout does not.

I have also already read this article:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

Which is doing virtually the same thing I want to do, however my device keeps showing the button *on top* of the `EditText` element:

[image: Button on top of EditText]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/search_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Ideally, the `EditText` element should be about 75% the width of my device and the button the remaining 25%

I have next to 0 experience working with Layouts, and this is my first attempt at making a very simple app from scratch coming from a web background.

Comment: i never tryit but new appcompat api available for percentage relative layout when you can define width and height in percentage try it .
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent. 
or use linearlayout

Comment: An other example you can find here: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/

Answer (score 1):

You should use LinearLayout instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="@string/search_button" />
</LinearLayout >
```

**Edit:**
Alternative solution, but this way editText is fixed width and button get all the remaining width

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
        android:text="@string/search_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This probably goes into premature optimization, but the android developers post makes a case against using `LinearLayout` and they do a similar example to mine using just a RelativeLayout. 

Is there any technical feature that prevents me from using a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: check the relative layout alternative

Comment: actually the second solution is better, however if you insist you need **percentage** width, you may need LinearLayout, or you could try replacing the second solution with PercentageRelativeLayout. However, don't trust too much about the performance impact. The performance impact argument started years ago, and that still wasn't a problem at that time. You should forget it unless you are having over 3 or 4 layers of LinearLayout.

Comment: well I don't *need* it, I'm coming from a web background so I'm used to say things like `width:80%` but I think that doesn't directly translate to Android Layouts.

Comment: Then, I would guess the second solution should fit what you need, maybe you need to add some margin / padding though

Comment: so, does it answer you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute `android:layout_toRightOf = "@id/editText"` in **Button** and give fix width to button like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ems = "15"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
        android:text="@string/search_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

No need to use extra attributes like `android:layout_alignParentTop` etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you gave `fill_parent` as width to both element. `fill_parent` means *same width as parent*, so they cannot be horizontally aligned (by the way, you should use `match_parent` instead, they are the same, but the former has been deprecated years ago...). To have them sitting beside each other you should do something like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Put the Button first, so the EditText can occupy all the remaining space -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="@string/search_button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/search_button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_button"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sadly you have no way to give a percentage. To accomplish this you need to use `LinearLayout` and give weights:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:text="@string/search_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```